# How can I get my Cygwin SSH server to log into a file?

Tags: windows, cygwin, logging, sshd, syslog

On proper Linux systems, the SSH server typically logs into a file, e.g. `/var/log/auth.log` or `/var/log/syslog` etc. But - that doesn't exist on my Cygwin system; and merely editing `/etc/sshd_config` doesn't help. What do I do to enable such logging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the following:

1. Check whether sure you have an up-to-date Cygwin's setup utility (typically named `setup-x86_64.exe`); if you don't have one, get it from Cygwin.com.
2. Run the Cygwin setup utility
3. Switch to Full package view (all packages
4. Search for `syslog-ng` in the search box
5. Double-click "Skip" to replace it with the recommended version (... assuming `syslog-ng` isn't already installed)
6. Press 'Ok' or 'Continue'. Additional packages may get installed, as the setup utility updates your already-installed packages.
7. After installation is concluded, start a Cygwin terminal *As Administrator* (right-click the shortcut and select "Run as Administrator" on the menu).
8. Execute `/bin/syslog-ng-config`.
9. Let `syslog-ng` be installed as a service (i.e. say "yes yes yes" to the configuration questions...)
10. Start the syslog service by running `net start syslog-ng`.
11. Edit the logging-relating lines in `/etc/sshd_config`:
12. Uncomment `SysLogFacility` and set it to `LOCAL5` (that's local-five, not local-s)
13. Uncomment `LogLevel` (and set it to whatever you like)
14. Restart the Cygwin SSH service: `net stop cygsshd` and `net start cygsshd`

That should do it.

<sub>(This solution is based on these instructions.)</sub>

note: link has been modified as redirects to malware site.

Comment: This had no effect for me (but thankfully the issue I was trying to resolve, passwordless ssh keys, magically fixed itself). `/var/log/cygsshd.log` still is empty (well, shows an old message when I was trying a different config). I'd been screwing with the users, which could be part of the problem.